iCloud family sharing: is there any notifications to others member if you start/end share your geo location
iCloud family sharing: is there any notifications to others member if you start/end share your geo location?

There are two ways to hide your location:

Remove an individual person from your sharing list. This will show up in your iMessage conversation as a note saying something like "XYZ stopped sharing their location." It should not send a normal notification when you stop sharing, but they will see it in the conversation.
This will send a notification if you share with them later, since it's seen as a new share.

Turn off "Share My Location" in Find My > Me. This will stop sharing your location with everyone temporarily and does not send notifications. If they try to view your location it will indicate a location is not being shared.
This will not send a notification either when it's turned off or back on.


